# How to convert Curl request call to a Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api, curl

I was working with a Sentiment Analysis API which requires a curl request to get the JSON object.

How can this be done with AJAX?

This is the curl request:

```
$ curl -d "text=great" http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/
```

This is what I have tried:

```
$.ajax("http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/", {
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ text: "Hello world!" }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    }).done(function(data){
        alert('done'); 
    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){

});
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: $.ajax("http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/", {
  type: "POST",
     data: JSON.stringify({ text: "Hello world!" }),
     contentType: "application/json",
  }).done(function(data){
   alert('done');
  }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
 
  });

Comment: any console errors when you use that code?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)
popup.html:1 Failed to load http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present

Comment: Please, put the error message in your question rather than in commentaries.

Comment: this means the remote API doesn't support CORS requests, so you cannot use AJAX to access this API. You'll have to write a server-side script to access the API, and then load the response into your web page.